# make excel files use a global workbook function with vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and I have problem understanding the workbooks in vba for excel files.
I have a macro called Addin.xla, this macro is used by 2000 files.

The problem that I have, is that the 2000 files have its own `thisworkbook` thats declares the function `Workbook_BeforeClose`. All the 2000 files have the exact same `Workbook_BeforeClose`.

What I want to do is to change the `Workbook_BeforeClose` function in all the 2000 files. Can I make the files use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` function in the Addin.xla file or must I change the same `Workbook_BeforeClose` function for all 2000 files?

If the later is the case, can someone show me how to write a macro that loops through all the files and updates this function automatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to delegate the function to the addin:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    runCleanupCode
End Sub
```

where `runCleanupCode` is located in your addin. That means that if you want to make changes in the future, you only need to make them in the addin.

To change the code in all your sheets, you can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846894/how-to-add-delete-lines-of-code-to-a-thisworkbook-of-excel-file-using-vb-net).

Comment: I think he needs to use the Application Workbook_BeforeClose event rather than the Addin Workbook_beforeClose event.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams I was probably not clear: the `Workbook_BeforeClose` is in the individual files, only `runCleanupCode` is in the addin.

Answer (score 3):

In the addin, handle the `Application.WorkbookBeforeClose` event.

But if you already have same code in 2000 files, you will have to remove it anyway. Otherwise it will run in addition to the handler you will define in the addin.

To auto remove:

Add a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility X.X.`

Then open each file in a loop and do

```
With currentWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
  .DeleteLines .ProcStartLine("Workbook_BeforeClose", vbext_pk_Proc), .ProcCountLines("Workbook_BeforeClose", vbext_pk_Proc)
End With
```